# Prerequisites for a book

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As I have been reading through Hartman ordinary differential sometimes I see exercises assumes some high background.

My question is what are the prerequisites for Hartman ordinary differential equations?

Comment: What is this "high background" specifically? Can you give examples?

Comment: like the exercises in the 6th section of chapter 5

Comment: it assumes that you know about tensors and these stuffs

Comment: Every book has an appendix. Have you tried looking there?. Else you can also refer to Lawrence Perko's book

Comment: Why are you reading this book? If you are looking for an introduction to ODEs, that may not be the best choice.

Comment: I look for comprehensive books that is the thing.

Comment: The appendices in the book are additional topics with higher level of theory  not background material

Comment: Please don't assume all of us have the book at hand and can look up those specific exercises.